# Weird behaviour of strotime comparison

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I can't understand what's wrong whit this code I wrote, and why it has an  unintuitive behavior

```
if(($datav == 0) || ((strtotime($datav)) > (strtotime('01/01/2014')))) {
echo 'yes';
}

else if((strtotime($datav)) < (strtotime('01/01/2014'))) {
echo 'no';
        }
```

$datav is a date variable which can or can't be set in a wordpress form I wrote.

here is what's happening: if the date is not set (== 0) the code works, it echoes 'yes'; if the date is set and is before 01/01/2014 it also works, it echoes 'no'; but if the date is set and is after 01/01/2014 it doesn't work and echoes 'no'.
in the third case, I'm sure I've set the right date (a date after 01/01/2014) because I echoed it to check it.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks anyone.

Comment: What is the date format you are passing to `$datav`

Comment: strtotime is picky about the date formats it works with. If you format the date YYYY-MM-DD it works, otherwise as you have now, it assumes MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: You could simply solve this problem by yourself, if your would just debug your variables and `strtotime()`, like: `var_dump(strtotime($datav))` etc. You would quickly see that result is probably `false` or wrong timestamp...

Comment: Uhm, how can I know the date format? Unfortunately I don't have direct access to the database and I think wordpress may be changing it to european standard format (dd/mm/yyyy) in the forms and outputs.
Anyway, I just wrote 2014-01-01 instead of 01/01/2014 in the code and nothing changed :/

Comment: thanks Glavić, I'll try. Sorry but I'm a php newbie!

Comment: ok, I think I found what's wrong, the var dump gives bool(false) as a result, so I think I'm doing something wrong in the form. I'll check there, thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$datav = 0;

test('2014-01-01');

test('2015-01-01');

test('01/01/2013');

test('25/12/2014'); // fail because strtotime will resolve as 1970-01-01

function test($datav) {

    echo "Input Date: $datav = ";

    $timestamp = strtotime($datav);

    if ($datav == 0 || $timestamp > strtotime('01/01/2014')) {
        echo 'yes';
    } else if ($timestamp < strtotime('01/01/2014')) {
        echo 'no';
    } else {
        echo 'neither';
    }

    echo " - What strtotime thinks was input (".date('d-M-Y', $timestamp).")<br />";
}
```